# Hyperledger Fabric on Raspberry pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to deploy hyperledger fabric on a raspberry pi, but it doesn't  work. I'm searching for some tutorial but i didn't found it, there are someone that just did it?

Answer (score 4):

Last time I've tried to run Hyperledger Fabric on RPi I've prepared following instructions:

1. Install latest RASPBIAN on SD card, you can download image from: 
   https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/
2. Update and upgrade latest by running:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
   ```
3. Install required dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install git curl gcc libc6-dev libltdl3-dev python-setuptools -y
   ```
4. Upgrade python pip installer:

   ```
   sudo -H pip install pip --upgrade
   ```
5. Install docker and docker compose:

   ```
   curl -sSL get.docker.com | shsudo usermod -aG docker pisudo pip install docker-compose
   ```
6. Logout/Login terminal session, so changes will take effect.
7. Install golang, by following instructions from: https://golang.org/doc/install
8. Create golang directory:

   ```
   mkdir -p /home/pi/golang && mkdir -p /home/pi/golang/src/github/hyperledger/
   ```
9. Define environment variable

   ```
   export GOPATH=/home/pi/golang
   ```
10. Make sure go binaries are in the path, e.g.:

    ```
    export PATH=/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH
    ```
11. Clone fabric-baseimage repository into `/home/pi/golang/src/github/hyperledger/`

    ```
    git clone https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-baseimage.git
    ```
12. Clone client fabric repository into `/home/pi/golang/src/github/hyperledger/`

    ```
    git clone https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric.git
    ```
13. Build based docker images

    ```
    cd ~/golang/src/github/hyperledger/fabric-baseimage && make docker-local
    ```
14. Apply following patch to fabric code base:

    ```
    --- a/peer/core.yaml
    +++ b/peer/core.yaml
    @@ -68,7 +68,6 @@ peer:

         # Gossip related configuration
         gossip:
    -        bootstrap: 127.0.0.1:7051
             # Use automatically chosen peer (high avalibility) to distribute blocks in channel or static one
             # Setting this true and orgLeader true cause panic exit
             useLeaderElection: false
    @@ -280,7 +279,7 @@ vm:
                     Config:
                         max-size: "50m"
                         max-file: "5"
    -            Memory: 2147483648
    +            Memory: 16777216
    ```

    AND

    ```
    --- a/core/container/util/dockerutil.go
    +++ b/core/container/util/dockerutil.go
    @@ -45,6 +45,7 @@ func NewDockerClient() (client *docker.Client, err error) {
     // and GOARCH here.
     var archRemap = map[string]string{
            "amd64": "x86_64",
    +       "arm": "armv7l",
     }

     func getArch() string {
    ```
15. Build Hyperledger peer and

    ```
    cd ~/golang/src/github/hyperledger/fabric && make clean peer peer-docker
    ```
16. Peer executable binary will appear in:

    `~/golang/src/github/hyperledger/fabric/build/bin/`

Comment: when i try to do make clean peer peer-docker i have the error docker: Error response from daemon: manifest for hyperledger/fabric-baseimage:armv7l-0.3.1 not found.

Comment: Which problem do you have?

Comment: Have you tried to build images as described at step #13?

Comment: Unable to find image 'hyperledger/fabric-baseimage:armv7l-0.3.1' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: manifest for hyperledger/fabric-baseimage:armv7l-0.3.1 not found.
See 'docker run --help'.
Makefile:215: recipe for target 'build/docker/gotools' failed
make: *** [build/docker/gotools] Error 125

Comment: yes i build it using: make -f Makefile. I did it like this because docker-local doesn't works

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:~/golang/src/github/hyperledger/fabric-baseimage $ make docker-local
make: *** No rule to make target 'docker-local'.  Stop.

Comment: Probably I've solved with precompiled images for raspberry at https://hub.docker.com/u/frbrkoala/

Comment: Is this guide still valid? I also got "make: * No rule to make target 'docker-local'. Stop." when running "make docker-local". "make docker" runs, but only once the Docker repo is changed from "armv7/armhf-ubuntu" to "arm32v7/ubuntu/" in the Makefile. Would this solution also work?

Comment: I think there was changes which requires some adjustments