# How to set up a raspberry pi to a fabric network, to use hyperledger composer?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I need to implement a decentralized hyperledger composer but I am not sure what to do.

I want my raspberry pi to be a participant on a fabric network, created by hyperledeger composer tool.

Answer (score 1):

Hyperledger Composer isn't supported on Raspbian - list of supported OS in the prereqs here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/installing-prereqs.html

Furthermore you have the challenge of running Fabric on your Pi - see more on this S/O thread here -> [Hyperledger Fabric on Raspberry pi 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45800167/hyperledger-fabric-on-raspberry-pi-3)

Comment: Here is the updated prereqs list link: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs