# Is it possible to run HyperLedger Fabric 2.0 in Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: raspberry-pi, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm currently using Raspberry Pi 3 with the newest Raspbian Buster version. I followed the installation guide here:

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/install.html

and installed all the prerequisites beforehand: curl, docker, docker-compose, go, python, nodejs.

But the moment I run the fabric-samples installation command:
`curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s`

I encounter the following error:

```
Clone hyperledger/fabric-samples repo

===> Cloning hyperledger/fabric-samples repo and checkout v2.0.0
Cloning into 'fabric-samples'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 19, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (19/19), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (18/18), done.
remote: Total 4685 (delta 4), reused 7 (delta 1), pack-reused 4666
Receiving objects: 100% (4685/4685), 1.67 MiB | 193.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2330/2330), done.
error: pathspec 'v2.0.0' did not match any file(s) known to git

Pull Hyperledger Fabric binaries

===> Downloading version 2.0.0 platform specific fabric binaries
===> Downloading:  https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/download/v2.0.0/hyperledger-fabric-linux-armv7l-2.0.0.tar.gz
--2020-02-10 17:04:37--  https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/download/v2.0.0/hyperledger-fabric-linux-armv7l-2.0.0.tar.gz
Resolving github.com (github.com)... 13.229.188.59
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|13.229.188.59|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2020-02-10 17:04:37 ERROR 404: Not Found.

tar (child): hyperledger-fabric-linux-armv7l-2.0.0.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
rm: cannot remove 'hyperledger-fabric-linux-armv7l-2.0.0.tar.gz': No such file or directory
==> There was an error downloading the binary file.

------> 2.0.0 platform specific fabric binary is not available to download <----
```

It seems that the fabric binaries and images are unavailable for armv7 processors. Other answers such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45800167/hyperledger-fabric-on-raspberry-pi-3) show me how to build the fabric binaries and images manually, but I still don't know how to get the fabric-samples to run afterwards.

Does anyone know how to install Hyperledger Fabric on RPi such that I can run the samples like [byfn](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/build_network.html) and [fabcar](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/write_first_app.html) as smoothly as in the documentation?

Comment: Hi @jonahcancio, Did you find out anything? I'm interested on this topic also. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Raspberry now has a 64bit OS which you will need to run Hyperledger Fabric (https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=275370).

I have made the docker images for this OS already for my own project which you can find if you follow this repo https://github.com/SurfTheRepo/HLF-for-RPI-. If you clone the repo you will find the binaries for the 64bit OS in the bin folder. I have some links explaining how I built the images and binaries in the readme.

Everything is for HLF2.3 btw.

I have been able to run the test-network on my raspberry using this.

But my Raspberry Pi is a model 4 and is 8GB, I dont think it will be possible on a Pi3, (the RAM usuage goes up to about 4gb when I run the test-work).

Im still working on this project so I'm changing the repo pretty often, but you should be able to get a general idea of how it all works from it.